# How to use XPtr

Tags: c++, r, pointers, rcpp

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to use `Rcpp::XPtr`.

I want to pass an R list of integer vectors to C++, convert it to `std::vector<std::unordered_set<int> >`, return it to R as an `Rcpp::XPtr`, and reuse it in a later C++ function.

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <omp.h>
#include <cstddef>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::XPtr<std::vector<std::unordered_set<int> > > convert_to_cpp_type(Rcpp::List& x) {
  std::size_t x_size = x.size();
  std::vector<std::unordered_set<int> > y(x_size);

  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < x_size; ++i) {
    Rcpp::IntegerVector x_i = x[i];
    y[i].insert(x_i.begin(), x_i.end());
  }

  Rcpp::XPtr<std::vector<std::unordered_set<int> > > z(y);
  return z;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector use_xptr(SEXP a) {
  Rcpp::XPtr<std::vector<std::unordered_set<int> > > b(a);
  std::size_t b_size = (*b).size();
  std::vector<double> c (b_size);  

  #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(10)
  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < b_size; ++i) {
    c[i] = example_function((*b)[i]);
  }

  return Rcpp::wrap(c);
}
```

This code does not compile, but it should provide an idea of what I aim to do. `a` in the second function is the `XPtr` exported by the first function.

There should be multiple errors in this code. However, even after hours of browsing Stack Overflow, the Rcpp website, and various other sites, I did not figure out how to correctly implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first function doesn't compile because the XPtr constructor needs a raw pointer, not a `std::vector`. However, the returned pointer will be worse than useless because it is pointing to a local variable that goes out of scope after the function returns. If you try to use it later then your session will crash.

The following function will return a valid pointer to a `std::vector<std::unordered_set>>`:

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction("

Rcpp::XPtr<std::vector<std::unordered_set<int> > > 
convert_to_cpp_type(Rcpp::List x) {

  typedef std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>> obj;
  std::size_t x_size = x.size();
  obj* y = new obj;

  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < x_size; ++i) {
    Rcpp::IntegerVector x_i = x[i];
    std::unordered_set s(x_i.begin(), x_i.end());
    y->push_back(s);
  }

  Rcpp::XPtr<obj> z(y);
  return z;
  
}")
```

To get the contents of the object indexed by the pointer, we need to build an R list again:

```r
cppFunction("

Rcpp::List use_xptr(SEXP a) {

  Rcpp::XPtr<std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>> b(a);
  Rcpp::List out;
  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < b->size(); ++i) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector x_i((*b)[i].begin(), (*b)[i].end());
    out.push_back(x_i);
  }
  return out;
  
}")
```

For completeness, let's create a function that we can call from R which modifies our C++ object (since we don't have `example_function`

```r
cppFunction("

void do_stuff(Rcpp::XPtr<std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>> x) {

  x->push_back(std::unordered_set<int> {0, 1, 2, 3});
  return;

}")
```

Now in R we can do:

```r
x <- list(1:10, 3:7)

x
#> [[1]]
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 3 4 5 6 7

xptr <- convert_to_cpp_type(x)

xptr
#> <pointer: 0x0000023659ab57c0>

do_stuff(xptr)

use_xptr(xptr)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 7 6 5 4 3
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3 2 1 0
```

This seems like an unnecessarily difficult way to do things. It would seem to me to make more sense to send a list to C++, have it do all the calculations you want, and return the result. The pointer doesn't really help you here.

Comment: Wow, thank you, I really appreciate your answer. Two quick clarification questions. (i) Are XPtrs tread-safe? I.e. could I loop over `x` in your `do_stuff` function with OpenMP? (ii) How do I deallocate the memory referenced by the pointer and thereby avoid a memory leak from using a pointer? Do I `rm` the object in R or do I `delete` it in C++?

Comment: As for memory leaks, a `std::vector` will be deallocated only once the pointer is removed / goes out of scope in R _and_ garbage collection is run. But what I don't understand is why you _need_ an `XPtr` at all in this situation. Why do you need to have a pointer exported to R only to pass it back in to your own C++ code as opposed to passing objects or references directly between your own C++ functions? Remember, your exported C++ functions are free to call other non-exported C++ functions. Can you explain a bit more about what you think the `XPtr` is allowing you to do here?

Comment: Thanks. The example I used is strongly simplified. The main purpose of splitting the C++ code into these two stages is to get rid of the R list in between. That list's vectors contain hundreds of millions of elements each. It is a massive object. If I created the `std::vector` from the list in the second stage, I would have to keep the list in RAM throughout that stage of C++ functions because deleting R objects from C++ is not safe. And that would not leave enough RAM for all the other operations performed in the second stage. Like many researchers, I am not at liberty to just add more RAM.

Comment: @user thanks, that explains it a bit better. However, your R list and `std::vector` will both be present in RAM after the `XPtr` is created. Is it simply the case that you want to delete the contents of the list in R after the XPtr is returned so that you can delete the list in R before proceeding with further calculations?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is what I want to do.

Comment: @user in that case, you can empty you R list as you fill up the standard vector. As you iterate through the list creating your unordered sets, add the line `x(i) = R_NilValue;` at the bottom of the loop. This will turn your R list into a list of NULL values. Back in R, your initial list will be a list of NULLs of negligible size, but won't have diappeared altogether. No need to go back to R with an XPtr just to delete your list to free up memory. It can all be done in C++

Comment: You can even iterate through the list and `erase` elements to produce an entirely empty list back in R

Comment: Does any of the two methods lead to data being copied? Or is the R list being updated in place?

Comment: @user the R list is modified in place.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing advice. I tried simply assigning other values to the R objects from C++ before, but I guess I did something wrong. Thanks again. Incredibly helpful discussion.